# Does anyone know how to programmatically determine the ME (Manageability Engine) FW Version?

Tags: winapi, version, intel, bios, firmware

For Intel AMT Management Engine supported machines, you can manually find the ME FW Version in the BIOS on the Advanced tab under ME Configuration.  Does anyone know how to this programmatically (preferably with C#)?  I've Googled till I turned blue, and manually searched through all the common (and uncommon) WMI namespaces (including Win32_BIOS) using WMI Code Creator, but can't find a way to read this property.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have enabled AMT?  If so you can download the AMT SDK and there are APIs that return FW version information.  You could take a look at the SDK Sample in the following folder: \Windows\Intel_AMT\Samples\WS-Management\GeneralInfo

The SDK also has a scripting library - if you go into the documentation, search for "FW Version" and you can see the Scripting Library on the left panel - there are instructions on how to use it.  The SDK is here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-the-latest-intel-amt-software-development-kit-sdk/

Though, since this question is 2 years old, I hope you have found an answer by now...

Answer (score 0):

Another way of checking the ME FW version is to query the `ME_System` WMI class located here: `ROOT\Intel_ME:ME_System` for the property `FWVersion`

Answer (score 0):

There is a caveat for the solution above. It requires the Intel Manageability Service is installed LMS via a SetupME.EXE installation.

SMS_AMTObject used to exist with some AMT information, but you needed SCCM installed, you can still use it with SCCM if you have installed the Intel SCS Addon.

There are 2 non-WMI ways of getting Intel AMT version (both Intel tools):

- SCSDiscovery.exe which writes to the registry very detailed AMT Information. Takes quite a few seconds to run.
- FWDetect.exe which can be used to determine if AMT FW Version is less, equal or greater to a specified version. Very quick.